# Datalist not fixed to textbox when web page is scrolled

Tags: html

I want a textbox which also has a dropdown. It should also be able to search from the dropdown options. The below code satisfies the above requirement but when the page is scrolled down, the dropdown moves along with the page instead of being fixed to the textbox.

```html
<datalist id="browsers"  style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow: scroll; width: 100%; height:500px">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
```

[image]

Comment: After I scrolled down, dropdown closed. Did I understand wrong?

Comment: @Berkay It doesn't close for me instead it moves with the web page.

Comment: Can you produce it on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Berkay But you can see the problem if you run my snippet.

Comment: @Berkay I've posted a screenshot of the problem. You can see that the dropdown isn't fixed to the textbox.

Comment: This only happens inside of an `iframe`: [example in `iframe`](https://jsfiddle.net/f11q8p9w/), [example not in `iframe`](https://jsfiddle.net/f11q8p9w/1/)

Comment: When inside an `iframe` it doesn't close when scrolling outside of the frame, but when not inside an `iframe`, it closes when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Chosen`? `Chosen`  is really effective in this purpose. You can not only search inside a drop down but also be able to  select multiple items at a time too.

Have a look her in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oj3cjw9w/)